# I can't install org-checklist

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to install `org-checklist` for spacemacs but I'm having some difficulties. On the project documentation (https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-checklist.html) it says enable the `org contrib` directory but when I run `M-x find-library RET org-contribdir` it says the contrib directory is deprecated. When I try installing `org-plus-contrib` with `package-list-packages`, nothing happens.

[How to untick checkboxes in org-mode for the next cyclic/repetitive task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164918/how-to-untick-checkboxes-in-org-mode-for-the-next-cyclic-repetitive-task) - This stack overflow question says I should download the `org-checklist.el` file but I can't find it anywhere. If anyone knows how to set up `org-checklist` or a viable alternative, I'd be really grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-checklist.el` is part of `org-plus-contrib`. You *should* be able to install it with `package-manager`: it is available from orgmode.org, so you have to add `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)` to your list of archives.

Starting from `emacs -q` I was able to install it after evaluating these lines:

```el
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

in the `*scratch*` buffer. Invoking `package-list-packages` showed `org-plus-conrib` as an available package and `ix` installed it (after I confirmed that I wanted to install it).

I was then able to load `org-checklist` with `M-x load-library RET org-checklist RET`.

Alternatively, you can just download the file from [here](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/raw/master/contrib/lisp/org-checklist.el) and save it in some place that is found in your emacs's `load-path`, then say `(require 'org-checklist)`.

Hope this helps.